# How to maintain hierarchy in Oracle when entering values

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the table I am creating.

```
id   name   county
101  joe    USA
103  moe    USA
102  foe    USA
```

Now, problem I am facing is Oracle SQL, I want the id number by order. Mistake happens to a lot while I am inserting data. So, in that case, even I am inserting id number 2 after id number 3 but I want the id number 2 should be placed before id number 3. Hope you understand my question and able to answer it as I want.

Answer (score 3):

strictly speaking you shouldn't care about the *storage* sequence.  and *retrieval* order, via select, is easily addressed by an '**order by id**'.

now, if id is not specified by you, but is instead an auto-incremented field (where the database adds +1 for each row insertion) and you want to have an arbitrary order on it, other than that of insertion, then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY ID` to sort your results according to id. But if you want to maintain the sequence in which you entered your records, irrespective of values of id, then you may want to create a `SEQUENCE`.
Try this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
```

This will create an auto-increment sequence. Then you can use `ORDER BY` clause and sort your results according to this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

JL Peyret is telling right in database level you no need to worry about your storage. what you can worry about is retrieval in select that you can sort using "Order by".

But for any reason if you want to store data in your table also in sorted order, I think you can follow below sequence in some frequency may be weekly or monthly -

- take data from this table to another temp table.
- truncate this table.
- insert into this table using temp table using "Order By".

Comment: it would work. but it may create problems if the id field is a foreign key somewhere.  seems to me the OP is a beginner at SQL.  which is fine.  however sql is very much designed to not be concerned about storage considerations.  we might as well communicate that feature/limitation up front to him and hope he either rephrases his requirements or figures out that they are not needed/supported by relational dbs.